# jQuery find closest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the a href of an list item.

**HTML**

```
<div class="popup" style="display: none;">
    <div class="product">           
        <div class="photo">
            <a href="" class="sendkleur" id="link69"> <!-- href im trying to reach -->     
                <img id="product-collection-image-69" src="" alt="Test kleur" class="popup-image69"> 
            </a>
        </div>
        <a href="" class="sendkleur" id="link69">        
           <strong>Test kleur</strong>  
        </a>
        <span class="swatchLabel-category">Kleur:</span>
        <p class="float-clearer"></p>
       <div class="swatch-category-container" style="clear:both;" id="ul-attribute137-69">
             <img onclick="listSwitcher();" src="" id="a137-32" class="swatch-category" alt="Beige" width="12px" height="12px" title="Beige">
              <img onclick="listSwitcher();" src="" id="a137-36" class="swatch-category" alt="Zwart" width="12px" height="12px" title="Zwart">
        </div>
    <p class="float-clearer"></p>    
    </div>                   
</div>
```

There are multiple popups on the site and thats what makes it difficult. At first I used this code

```
var link = jQuery('.photo').find('a')[0].getAttribute("href");
```

But this ofcourse only returns the `href` of the first popup. Then I tried this code:

```
var link = jQuery('.photo').closest('a').attr("href");
```

But this returned `undefined`

Then I tried this:

```
 var link = jQuery(this).closest('a').attr("href");
```

But that also returns `undefined`

**Edit**
Here is the whole jQuery code snippet

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.swatch-category-container img').click(function(){


        var kleur = jQuery(this).attr('title');
        var link = jQuery('.photo').find('a').attr("href");
        console.log(link);
        link += "?kleur="+kleur;
        console.log(link);
        jQuery('.photo').find('.sendkleur').attr("href", link);


    });
});
```

Comment: what is `this` referring to?

Comment: What event are you working from, and what data are you trying to retrieve? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @ArunPJohny To the clicked element `.swatch-category-container img`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working from the `.swatch-category-container img` element, you can traverse the DOM to find the required `a` like this:

```
$('.swatch-category-container img').click(function() {
    var link = $(this).closest('.popup').find('.photo a').prop('href');

    // do something with link here...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If `this` is the `.swatch-category-container img` element then, the `anchor` is the previous to previous sibling of the ancestor `swatch-category-container` element

```
var link = jQuery(this).closest('.swatch-category-container').prev().prev().attr("href");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said multiple popups, the idea would be like this.

```
1. Get all popups
2. From each popup in all popups
     Get the photo href item


 $('.popup').each(function() {
      var hrefItem = $(this).find('.photo a').attr('href');
      //Do your processing with href item

   });
```